# How to pause flash application in browser?

Tags: flash, browser

How to pause flash application in browser if there isn't any buttons that would allow it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Well, there is a website, there is a swf file, i want to pause it.*

Do you have access to these files and their source? Is it on the same domain?

Anyway, the previous two answers suggested wrapping the swf with another Flash application and then setting the framerate to 0. That's not accurate, because the minimum framerate you can set is 0.01. Flash code is built around the framerate, it makes sense. 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate

If you have access to the original files you want to pause, the proper way to accomplish this would be through ExternalInterface

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

http://www.viget.com/inspire/bi-directional-actionscript-javascript-communication/

Comment: I don't have the full access.I can download the swf file though, but it get information online.So if I don't have the original .fla file the only way is to pause it is to wrap it in another flash file ? Or is it possible via some browser tricks ? To pause browser also would be the choice if everything in it paused

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish, to my experience, can be done only if you know what's going on inside the wrapped swf (say, if you know there's a global function responsible for pausing). Lots of info on loading external SWF files can be found here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html
You cannot entirely pause everything on your own if the application doesn't support it. Even if the framerate was settable to 0 externally, sounds would still play, events would still dispatch. The author of the original Flash file must have a method responsible for the pausing.

Comment: Maybe reading this article will also help understand the complexity of the subject http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html#WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-7ffc
The marked page explains about the unloadAndStop function which does a similar thing to what you want, but of course, the SWF is unloaded and thus cannot be resumed to the same state (only loaded from scratch again).

Answer (score 2):

yes by adding this `stage.frameRate = 0;`

[pause flash](http://mokshalstudios.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/easiest-way-to-pause-game-as3/)

[Pause-Game-Using-stage-framerate](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?358747-Pause-Game-Using-stage-framerate)

[pause using javascript](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/)

Comment: adding it where ? I can't modify swf file

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, I'm a little confused at exactly what you want. I did find something that MIGHT help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277797/pause-flash-game-using-javascript). But here's what I saw that might help you out:

Embed an swf, that'll load the game. Then you'll be able to have some control, because the loaded SWF is running in the same instance as the loading SWF. For most games, it should suffice setting the frame rate to 0.

So setting the frame rate to 0 is essentially pausing it... But I would be able to provide a more detailed answer if you clarify your question a bit more.

Comment: Well, there is a website, there is a swf file, i want to pause it.