# How to pause a video on ie8

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, internet-explorer-8

How can I pause a video on ie8. Here I have two div's. just like a horizontal tabing concept, based on the button clicked i am displaying one of the div with a video. **my requirement is to pause the video if it is playing**, when I click on a button to switch to another div and I need to show the video that is there on the switched div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTrainingPopUp(page) {
        var offset;
        document.getElementById('PopUpDialog').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.display = "block";
        //offset = document.getElementById("divExternal").offsetWidth;
        offset = (document.width !== undefined) ? document.width : document.body.offsetWidth;
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.width = offset + "px";
        //offset = document.getElementById("divExternal").offsetHeight;
        offset = (document.height !== undefined) ? document.height : document.body.offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.height = offset + "px";
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.top = "0px";
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.left = "0px";
        if (page == 'phone') {
            document.getElementById('phoneTrainingDiv').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('portalTrainingDiv').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('phoneTrnBtn').value = "Phone Training Video >>";
            document.getElementById('portalTrnBtn').value = "Portal Training Video";
            document.getElementById("portalTrainingFrame").pause();  //will not work on IE8
        }
        if (page == 'portal') {
            document.getElementById('portalTrainingDiv').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('phoneTrainingDiv').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('portalTrnBtn').value = "Portal Training Video >>";
            document.getElementById('phoneTrnBtn').value = "Phone Training Video";
            document.getElementById("phoneTrainingFrame").pause();
        }
    }
    function hideTrainingPopUp() {
        document.getElementById('PopUpDialog').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('dimmerDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function setTrainingURL(dropdown){
         var url = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value; 
         document.getElementById("phoneTrainingFrame").src = url;

    }
</script>
</h:head>

<div id='dimmerDiv' class="divDimmer"></div>
<div id='PopUpDialog' class="popUpDialog">

    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="textTopAlign">
                <div style="padding: 1px;"><input type="button" id="portalTrnBtn" value="Portal Training Video" onclick="showTrainingPopUp('portal')" /></div> 
                <div style="padding: 1px;"><input type="button" id="phoneTrnBtn" value="Phone Training Video" onclick="showTrainingPopUp('phone')" ></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="borderGrayPadding15">
                    <div id="portalTrainingDiv" style="display: none;">
                        <!-- <iframe width="470" height="280" src="#{welcomeDataBean.portalTrainingURL}"> </iframe> -->
                        <embed id="portalTrainingFrame" width="470" height="280" src="#{welcomeDataBean.portalTrainingURL}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
                    </div>
                    <div id="phoneTrainingDiv" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="txtHeading5">What type of phone do you have? &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="phoneTypeID" onchange="setTrainingURL(this);">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="- Select -" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{welcomeDataBean.phoneTypeURLList}"/>
                        </h:selectOneMenu> </div><br />
                        <!-- <iframe id="phoneTrainingFrame" width="470" height="280"> </iframe> -->
                        <embed id="phoneTrainingFrame" width="470" height="280" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="closeBtnDiv">
                    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="hideTrainingPopUp()" class="hvdsPrimaryButton" /> <br /><br />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This all depends on how your chosen plugin works. Take a look at [flowplayers docs](http://flowplayer.org/docs/).

Comment: I couldn't able to figure out a simple way to pause the video. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried already? Where did you look? What problems did you find? We're not going to do the work for you...

Comment: Look at this answer, might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619276/how-to-pause-flash-application-in-browser

Comment: @Lix, I am not asking to work for me, insted asking for help. If you have any thing to share plz do share. I am new to css and js.  I need to play a mp4/wma videos on a model window. I triewd with embed tag with pause/stop methods, but these methods are not working on ie8. for this i am searching for a solution.

Comment: That is what I'm saying... If you've already tried something and it didn't work, tell us what you have tried and include any code you've written... From your question it doesn't look life you've tried anything